# I have a 30 x 20 matrix in Pandas that I'd like to convert into a 600 x 1 column array. Is that possible to do without Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to maintain the sequence so that each column is just added below the previous column. So Column1 first then column2 below that then column3 etc.

Comment: `df.melt()` ...?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer was assuming you wanted the row values to follow each other, you were ascking to put the columns "on top of each other". You can do that with:

```
df.melt().value.values
```

Sure. You can turn it into a numpy array, and the reshape it, passing the number of cells in the entire matrix as an argument. Assuming your matrix is called `df`, you can get the number of cells with `df.size`. That'll turn into a `1 x number-of-cells` array.

```
np.array(df).reshape(df.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=---'your dataframe'---
x = df.to_numpy()
y=[]
for i in x:
    for e in i:
        y.append(e)
print(y)
```

this code will give a list (size nx1)

```
array=np.array(y)
```

and this code will convert list to array.